# Question marks instead of non-ASCII symbols in Ruby gets using Windows terminal

Tags: ruby, windows, encoding, utf-8, terminal

I am new to Ruby and writing simple Ruby (without Rails) program, basically just one script file, and seem unable to get user entered Cyrillic text, e.g.

```
puts gets.chomp
```

returns `???` instead of `жжж`, but works just fine with English letters.

`puts gets.chomp.encoding` and `ruby -e 'p Encoding.default_external'` return `UTF-8`.

On this test

```
a = gets.chomp 
puts a == 'жжж'
puts a == '???'
```

`жжж` input produced

```
false
true
```

So they are stored as question marks.

I'm using Windows 10 command prompt (or working in RubyMine, which uses it anyway). Problem persists in pry and irb.

I've tried putting `#coding: UTF-8` at the beginning of the source file, didn't help. I've seen advise to edit some configuration files in Ruby on Rails project, but this is not my case.

Is there any simple solution?

Comment: First check: `puts gets.chomp.encoding`. What does it say?

Comment: @Casper `UTF-8`

Comment: What operating system and terminal are you using (my spidey sense says your terminal is the problem, not Ruby)?

Comment: Also check the output of this command: `ruby -e 'p Encoding.default_external'`.

Comment: What happens if you use `puts` in your script to output Cyrillic? If you still get question marks, then it might simply be a font issue. See the answer here, and you may also want to read the rest of the page for troubleshooting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/747437/823617

Comment: @Casper it is able to output Cyrillic. And I've tried this:

`a = gets.chomp`
`puts a == 'жжж'`
`puts a == '???'`

and `жжж` input produced
`false`, `true`
So they are stored as question marks.

Comment: @Casper is probably right in that its a terminal issue and has little to do with ruby.

Comment: Thanks @Casper! You were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a partial solution, maybe someone will find it helpful.

1. Change system locale in your Windows to Ukrainian/Belarusian/Russian etc (Control Panel -> Date and Time - > Change date and time -> Change calendar settings -> Administrative -> Change system locale).
2. Now you've got hexadecimal `\xNN\` output for Cyrillic input instead of question marks (like that: `\xA2\xE7\xB4`). I've found out that it's Windows encoding and by trial and error found the one that suits me - `CP866`, however, it lacks [some characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866). So passed string wasn't actually `UTF`, and we need to force its real encoding explicitly.
3. I've written this method to get a *real* `UTF-8` string from my `gets` input, which converts `CP866` string to `UTF-8` char by char (`require 'iconv'`).

```
def decode(string)
 string.force_encoding('CP866')
 Iconv.iconv('utf-8','ibm866', string).join('')
end
```

Another workaround I'm using is letting user enter `UTF` input in default notepad app, and then read it from the file, after user pressed some key:

```
system %{cmd /c "start #{file_to_open}"}
gets
input = File.open('file_to_open').read
```